# struts module configuration is not working?

Tags: java, struts, struts-1, struts-config, struts-html

I am not able to make modues in struts.my web.xml configuration file contains the below configuration :

**web.xml**

```
       <init-param>
        <param-name>config/admin</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/struts-config-admin.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

and my action configuraion in  struts-config-admin.xml is

```
    <action path="/userAdminAction"          type="com.admin.UserAdminAction"
         ............
     </action>
```

**JSP**   : **searchLayout.jsp**

```
<html:html>
     <html:form action="admin/userAdminAction.do" method="get">
        ..............
        ..............
        .............. 
         submit button to submit the form
    </html:form>
```

I am calling the jsp from the address bar using the url
       http://localhost/snpapp/admin/searchLayout.jsp

but I am getting following exception stack trace:
t cause of ServletException.

```
      servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot retrieve mapping for action: "/admin /userAdminAction"
     at org.apache.struts.taglib.html.FormTag.lookup(FormTag.java:840)
```

at org.apache.struts.taglib.html.FormTag.doStartTag(FormTag.java:467)
  at jsp_servlet._lrd.*search.*_searchLayout.*jsp*_tag7(__searchLayout.java:438)

I tried with different actions (Ex :action="/userAdminAction" or  action="userAdminAction.do") in jsp's form action but it is not working for modules.

Please give me some idea. how can i achive  struts moduels should work for forms ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be `admin/UserAdminAction`  instead of `admin/userAdminAction`, or your type parameter should be `type="com.admin.userAdminAction"`. Struts is case-sensitive

Comment: But my struts-config action is "userAdminAction" only.And it is wokring for without modules. but we are refactoring the code and making modues. so while making modularization jsp's html:form is giving the error.

Comment: I am sorry I think I completely misunderstood your question.